# SearchBlox custom paths setup

Tags: search, indexing, elasticsearch, web-crawler

I've got a path like: https://somesite/build/namez/javadoc/index.htm
Where namez - can change.

There are also paths like: https://somesite/build/namez/javadoc/somedoc/index.htm

I need to limit indexing only on https://somesite/build/*/javadoc/index.htm

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Allow Paths value within the SearchBlox Collection settings as follows:

/javadoc/

This will limit the crawler to only urls that contain /javadoc/.